# Working with Google Analytics GA4 in Delphi 10.4.2

Tags: android, delphi, google-analytics, firemonkey, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to send events from my mobile application to Google analytics.
External library connected:
`com-google-android-gms.play-services-analytics-impl.16.0.8.jar`
`Androidapi.JNI.PlayServices`

After launching the application, I get the following.

```
04-23 15:03:50.835 30878 30878 I GAv4    :   adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
04-23 15:03:50.835 30878 30878 I GAv4    :   adb logcat -s GAv4
04-23 15:03:50.869 30878 30878 D GAv4    : setLocalDispatchPeriod (sec): 5
04-23 15:03:51.506 30878 30986 D GAv4    : Sending first hit to property: 269XX9293
04-23 15:03:51.508 30878 30986 D GAv4    : Hit delivery requested: ht=1619179430868, _s=0, _v=ma12.4.51, a=2027768350, adid=7b03fae1-XXXX-4820-892a-ba3983eb6b7e, aid=com.XXXXXXX, an=XXXXXXX, ate=1, av=1.0.1, cid=24213dea-e355-XXXX-8b91-17087584684a, ea=lo
gin, ec=login, el=login, ev=87, sr=1080x2030, t=event, tid=269XX9293, ul=ru-ru, v=1
04-23 15:03:51.737 30878 30986 D GAv4    : Hit sent to the device AnalyticsService for delivery
```

Added to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>

        <!-- Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
             installation campaign reporting -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
```

To work with the Java class, the following class `com-google-android-gms.play-services-analytics-impl.16.0.8.jar` is used:

```
unit GoogleAnalytics;

interface

 uses
   System.SysUtils,

   System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
      Androidapi.JNI.PlayServices,
      Androidapi.Helpers,
      Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,     
      Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  {$ENDIF}
   FMX.Types;

type
     TwGoogleAnalytics=class
       private
        FCollectDataPermission
                      : boolean;
        FGoogleAppId,
        fClient_Id
                      : String;
        {$IFDEF ANDROID}
          FTracker    : Janalytics_Tracker;
          FGoogleAId, JClient_Id  : JString;
        {$ENDIF}
       public
         {$IFDEF ANDROID}
            JGA : Janalytics_GoogleAnalytics;
            property CollectDataPermission: boolean read FCollectDataPermission write FCollectDataPermission;
         {$ENDIF}
          constructor Create;
          procedure SetParams(const aGoogleAppID, aClient_Id:string);
          
         property GoogleAppId:string read FGoogleAppId;
     end;

implementation


 constructor TwGoogleAnalytics.Create;
  begin
   FGoogleAppId := '';
   fClient_Id   := '';
  end;

  procedure TwGoogleAnalytics.SetParams(const aGoogleAppID, aClient_Id : String);
  var
    Map1      : JMap;
    Hit       : JHitBuilders_HitBuilder;
    EventHit  : JHitBuilders_EventBuilder;
    Loger     : Janalytics_Logger;
  begin
   {$IFDEF ANDROID}
    CollectDataPermission := true;//(Ini.CollectDataPermission = PERMISSION_YES);

    JGA   :=  TJanalytics_GoogleAnalytics.JavaClass.getInstance( TAndroidHelper.Context );
    JGA.setDryRun(false);
    JGA.reportActivityStart( SharedActivity );

    FGoogleAId  :=  StringToJString(aGoogleAppID);
    JClient_Id  :=  StringToJString(aClient_Id);
    FTracker    :=  JGA.newTracker(FGoogleAid);

    if FTracker <> nil then
    Begin
      FTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
      FTracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);

      EventHit:= TJHitBuilders_EventBuilder.Create;

      EventHit.setAction(StringToJString('login'));
      EventHit.setCategory(StringToJString('login'));
      EventHit.setLabel(StringToJString('login'));
      EventHit.setValue(87);

      Map1 := EventHit.build;


      FTracker.send(Map1);

      JGA.setLocalDispatchPeriod(5);
    End;
   {$ENDIF}
   FGoogleAppId:=aGoogleAppID;
  end;
...
end.
```

But no data comes to analytics. There is a chance that the library is out of date. But how to download a new one, I do not know, in the description of the SDK there is an option to work only with gradle. As far as I know, this is not possible in Delphi. I will wait for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around in the documentation.  [GoogleAnalytics](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics) I found this.

This code is used for universal analytics not GA4 so if you are trying to use this to send data to GA4 its not going to work.

```
package com.example;

 class MyApp extends Application {
   public static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
   public static Tracker tracker;

   @Overwrite
   public void onCreate() {
     analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
     analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);

     tracker = analytics.newTracker("UA-000-1"); // Replace with actual tracker id
     tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
     tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
     tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
   }
 }
```

I pinged the team to find out if there is a GA4 version of this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am working with the library that comes with the latest Delphi 10.4.2 [com-google-android-gms.play-services-analytics-impl.16.0.8.jar] and even how to upgrade to 17.4.1, without using grandle I don't know.

Comment: Yes, the above code worked for universal google analytics. But I have not been able to connect firebase yet, there is no java class for this.

Answer (score 1):

To send data to GA4 you need to use the Firebase SDK, which sends events to Google Analytics https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics
The GAv4 in logcat is not about GA4 but the version 4 of the API of Universal Analytics

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it didn't even occur to me, I thought I was working with GA4. This development tool does not allow you to work with the firebase SDK directly. It is possible to connect jar libraries and work with their methods. But how to do it in this case, I do not know. The instructions say that you need to connect through gradle. In Delphi, there is no such possibility, but I don't know how to get the jar in this case. Perhaps there is a way to do this with the help of the Android studio intermediary, I will look for such an option.

Comment: Yes, the above code worked for universal google analytics. But I have not been able to connect firebase yet, there is no java class for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this library works for you:
https://github.com/sismais/GoogleAnalytics4Delphi

Readme file contains initial instructions and link to a demo.